# vs code TextEditorEdit does not insert a second time

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension that finds a pattern in a text, parses it into multiple lines of data, and then inserts this parsed data on the first line after where the match was found.

I am currently not sure how TextEditorEdit works, but at least I expect to see my results (although perhaps overlapping or not in the right position). The issue is that only the first text insert is actually visible, not any following inserts. I noticed that the second insert's onResolve thenable does not have success set to true. But why?

Here's the code:

```
matchlistItems.forEach(item => {
    let parsedMatch = parser.toString(item.text);
    let newText = newLine + parsedMatch + newLine;

    editor.edit(editBuilder => {
        let pos = new Position(pos1.line + item.line + 1, 0);
        editBuilder.insert(pos, newText);
        console.log(newText);
    }).then(success => {
        if (success) {
            editor.selection = new Selection(pos1, pos1);
        }
    }).then(undefined, err => {
        console.error(err);
    }); 
})
```

the console logs both `newText` values, but only the first is actually inserted into the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. Potentially something to do with the asynchronous nature of the `TextEditor.edit()` method, but you want to specify all edits in one go to the editBuilder callback.

In my case, this worked fine:

```
editor.edit(editBuilder => {
    matchlistItems.forEach(item => {
        let parsedMatch = parser.toString(item.text);
        let newText = newLine + parsedMatch + newLine;
        let pos = new Position(pos1.line + item.line + 1, 0);
        console.log(pos);
        editBuilder.insert(pos, newText);
    })
}).then(success => {
    if (success) {
        editor.selection = new Selection(pos1, pos1);
    } else {
        console.log(success);
    }
}).then(undefined, err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```